# Cycles of length 1(mod 3) in regular graphs

Tags: graph-theory, co.combinatorics

Does every 4-regular graph contain a cycle of length (number of edges in the cycle) $1 (\mod3)$? Are there only finitely many exceptions?

I suspect such cycles exist for most 3-regular graphs but 4-regularity is enough for what I'm investigating.

Comment: I guess you want the graph to be simple.  Take two vertices connected by 4 edges.  

Comment: Yes thanks for the correction, simple and connected.

Comment: Do you mean simple cycle?

Comment: Yes, the cycles are simple, too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0166-218X%2801%2900190-1), N. Dean et al. have shown that if a simple graph *G*

- is 2-connected,
- has minimum degree at least 3, and
- is not isomorphic to the Petersen graph,

then *G* contains a cycle of length 1 mod 3.

Now consider any 4-regular graph *H*. If I'm not mistaken, it's fairly easy to show that *H* contains a subgraph *G* such that two nodes of *G* have degree 3, all other nodes of *G* have degree 4, and *G* is 2-connected. Clearly *G* can't be the Petersen graph, and thus the above theorem implies that *G* (and therefore also *H*) contains a cycle of length 1 mod 3.

**Edit:** Here is how would construct *G* given *H*. Recall that *H* has a 2-factorisation, i.e., it consists of cycles such that each node of *H* is "covered" by exactly 2 cycles. If there are no articulation points in *H*, the claim is clear. Otherwise consider the [block tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconnected_component) of *H* and pick a biconnected component *K* that contains only one articulation point; let *x* be the articulation point. Consider the subgraph *K*' = *K* − *x*; this graph consists of one path *P* and a set of cycles, and each node of *K*' is covered by either *P* and one cycle or exactly 2 cycles. It may be the case that *K*' contains articulation points. However, each articulation point is an endpoint of a bridge, and each bridge is an edge of *P*. Remove all bridges and let *G* be one of the connected components in the resulting bridgeless graph.

Comment: Finding your subgraph G is easy, as you say: if H is not biconnected, find a block with only one articulation point adjacent to it, and let G be the remaining vertices in that block. If H is biconnected, you can just use H in place of G, since you don't actually require the existence of the two degree-three vertices, but if you really want them you can remove the last ear in an ear decomposition.

Comment: @David: I think you need to be a bit more careful in the construction of G; removing the articulation point may create new articulation points. I added a sketch of the construction of G above; essentially just do what you said, remove all bridges, and pick one of the components.

Answer (score 1):

This paper shows that such graphs may lack a cycle of a particular length:

Some 4-valent, 3-connected, planar, almost pancyclic graphs

S. A. Choudum

Discrete Mathematics, Volume 18, Issue 2, 1977, Pages 125-129

Abstract:

For each positive integer k (≠ 5,6), a 4-valent, 3-connected, planar graph, having cycles of all (possible) lengths except k is constructed.

Comment: This sounds interesting, however as I understand it these graphs do not provide a counterexample, that is they have some cycle of length 3m+1 for _some_ m.

Comment: Gjergij: Yes, that is correct. While not noted above there is quite a large literature about the existence (or lack of existence) of cycles in graphs, in particular mod m. Perhaps things are easier in the case that interests you for planar graphs. 